# Return aggregated data from federated query

Tags: aggregate, sparql, federated

I am working with SPARQL federated queries. I do not wish to return anything other than aggregated data from each service query. Is this possible? Currently, the query returns data from each service query, and then runs a count and group by. I tried to use subqueries, but they do not work. I am using a fuseki server.

<Edited - added sample query>

```
SELECT (COUNT(?var) as ?varCount)  ?var2
WHERE{      
   {          
       ?var a abc:Class;                                                       
   }    
UNION       
   {        
   SERVICE <https://sample1.org>    
       {              
       ?var a abc:Class;               
       ?var abc:var2 ?var2.                    
       }        
   }
UNION       
   {        
   SERVICE <https://sample2.org>    
       {              
       ?var a abc:Class;               
       ?var abc:var2 ?var2.                 
       }        
   }
} group by ?var2
```

Comment: Please show the query example. 

You can put aggregates to the SERVICE clause and aggregate the partial results in the caller.

Comment: Hi Andy, firstly, many thanks for your fast reply. I will add an example of a query above now.

Comment: Since you have DISTINCT, you can't count at the remote sites and combine locally.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a query I could run to aggregate the data at the remote sites? The most important thing is that aggregated data does not leave the remote sites.

Comment: AndyS, I removed DISTINCT from the query.

Comment: Now you can do 
`
SERVICE <https://sample2.org>    
       {  SELECT (COUNT(?var) as ?varCount)  ?var2 {
           ?var a abc:Class;               
           ?var abc:var2 ?var2.   
           } group by ?var2                
       }  ` and so a SUM overall `?varCount` returned from each part. Also can write as drop the UNION, do 3 calls, get ?varCount1, ?varCount2, ?varCount3 and BIND(?varCount1+?varCount2+?varCount3 AS ?varCount).